# php laravel What is the Stream() function in image intervention

Tags: php, image, laravel, intervention

I wonder what the stream() function in image intervention does? http://image.intervention.io/api/stream

Right now I am uploading my images to amazon S3 like this:

```
public function uploadLargeAndMainImages($file,$adId)
  {
    $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
    $extension = $file->guessExtension();
    $filename = uniqid() . '.' . $extension;

    //Create and resize images
    $image = Image::make($file)->resize(null, 600, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });
    $image->encode($extension);

    $imageLarge = Image::make($file)->resize(null, 800, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });
    $imageLarge->encode($extension);

    // upload image to S3
    $s3->put("images/{$adId}/main/" . $filename, (string) $image, 'public');
    $s3->put("images/{$adId}/large/" . $filename, (string) $imageLarge, 'public');

    // make image entry to DB
    $file = File::create([
        'a_f_id' => $adId,
        'file_name' => $filename,
    ]);

  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its all written in the [Intervention Docs](http://image.intervention.io/api/stream) you've mentioned above:

> The `stream()` method encodes the image in given format and given
>   image quality and creates new PSR-7 stream based on image data.

It returns a `PSR-7 stream` as instance of `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream`.

```
// encode png image as jpg stream
$stream = Image::make('public/foo.png')->stream('jpg', 60);
```

Just for the sake of demonstration you can use the `stream()` method with S3 like this:

```
...
$image_normal = Image::make($image)->widen(800, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->upsize();
});
$image_thumb = Image::make($image)->crop(100,100);
$image_normal = $image_normal->stream();
$image_thumb = $image_thumb->stream();

Storage::disk('s3')->put($path.$file, $image_normal->__toString());
Storage::disk('s3')->put($path.'thumbnails/'.$file, $image_thumb->__toString());
```

It think you get it!

Comment: But what is: ```creates new PSR-7 stream based on image data```
I am already using the encode function. http://image.intervention.io/api/encode Seems like they almost do the same thing

Comment: PSR 7 is the new encoding standard, which encode doesn't do, see this - http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/

Comment: Thanks for the info! I have accepted your answer now :) This is off topic, but is there any reason I should switch to PSR 7?

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi : can you help me, i got an error : 

> FatalErrorException in WebUserAjax.php line 68:
> Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream::stream()